# IEEE 754-like definition of "real" real numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, real-numbers

once I have mapped, geometrically or by
$\sin\left( \arctan\left( x \right) \right)$ 
the range $\left[ 0,+\infty  \right[$ into $\left[ 0,1 \right[$, it's very "nice" to write (real) numbers in $\left[ 0,1 \right[$ as 
$$\underset{n\to \infty }{\mathop{\lim }}\,\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{{{a}_{k}}}{{{2}^{k}}}}\quad \left( {{a}_{k}}\in \{0,1\} \right)$$ 
AFAIK the series converges, since 
$$\underset{n\to \infty }{\mathop{\lim }}\,\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{{{2}^{k}}}}$$ 
converges and it's also Cauchy.

I like this definition since it's a lot alike the IEEE 754 standard for the floating points, and, since every set
$\{{{a}_{1}},{{a}_{2}}...,{{a}_{n}},...\}$
can be put in correspondence with a member of $\wp \left( \mathbb{N} \right)$ and

$\left| \mathbb{N} \right|<\left| \wp \left( \mathbb{N} \right) \right|$, we get, for the numbers represented in this way, an argument similar to the Cantor's "diagonal theorem".

My problem is that those "numbers" cannot be easily summed up (nor multiplied) since (let me guess) the map
$\sin\left( \arctan\left( x \right) \right)$
is not linear.

Is there a way to do that or to show that the above definition is equivalent to the usual (e.g. Dedekind cuts) ones ?

Comment: Note that $$\sin\arctan x = \frac{x}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}} .$$

Comment: Let $f=\sin\circ\arctan$, then "addition" of your numbers is $x\oplus y=f(f^{-1}(x)+f^{-1}(y))$.

Comment: I'd say this representation of the numbers in $[0,1[$ supports an argument _very_ similar to Cantor's diagonalization argument; all that is lacking is a provision for dealing with the sequences ending in repeating $1$s; each of those represents a number that is already represented by a sequence ending in repeating $0$s, except for the sequence that represents $1$ (which is not in the interval at all).

Answer (score 1):

The reason that these numbers cannot be summed up is because they give all the real numbers on $[0,1]$! It would be very weird if there was an easy way to sum up a series that gave some bizarre transcendental number. Some of these are non-computable even!

It's pretty easy to show that this is the same as the Cauchy Sequence definition of the real numbers: Identify each limit with the sequence of partial sums. Then you need to prove that for every class of Cauchy sequences, there is a sequence that falls inside of it.

Comment: Thanks all.
I could avoid the previous pitfall by saying the the above series deals only with the decimal part of a real number.
So avoiding the transformation [0,+∞[ into [0,1[.
In this way it's easy to sum two real numbers < 0.5.
Multiplication is more difficult, but it can be done.
My main question still remains: how can I relate this definition to the (more usual) Dedekind definition ?
Thanks